# "Cannot find symbol" error in Java

Tags: java, symbols, jcreator

I've been programming for a few days, I'm using Deitel's How to program.

In this case the app class GradeBookTest is meant to create and use an object of the class GradeBook, but everytime I try to run GradeBookTest I get the cannot find symbol error.
I know it's probably something stupid but I've been looking for the solution without success.

GradeBook.java:

```
public class GradeBook
{
    public void displayMessage();
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Grade book!")
    }
}
```

GradeBookTest.java:

```
public class GradeBookTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook();

        myGradeBook.displayMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: You've got one nasty semicolon in the GradeBook class at the `public void displayMessage();` method. Get rid of that terminating semicolon. I'm surprised that that class will compile.

Comment: Is that `semi-colon` at the end of `displayMessage();` a typo here, or you are having it? Because that will give you an error, but not the one you are showing.

Comment: you should create two files, one with GradeBook.java the other GradeBookTest.java within same directory and compile them here with javac. In a real work your java code is in a package ( by example org.miprog.tests ) then into the corresponding direcotry org/miprog/tests/ . when compiling in place you should find your .class at the same place than your .jaav file. If missing ... it means not all classes have been compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some minor changes that will work for you

```
class GradeBook {
    public void displayMessage() { // removed semi colon from your code
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Grade book!"); // added semi colon to your code
    }
}

public class GradeBookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook();

        myGradeBook.displayMessage();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Welcome to the Grade book!
```

Comment: This will in no way help OP in understanding the problem he might be having. It would be better if you add some explanation on what did you change, and why?

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks for the suggestin, I have added comments in the code so that OP can understand the answer.

Comment: Wow thanks, it works now, seems like there is a mistake in the book because it tells you to put that removed semicolon.